# Adding list controls to panel in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel .
 in my Db i have a list of persons .. 
for each person in run time i add different attributes under them .
 i want all the persons to be list as a list (separate list for each person ) . i will add values later .

here is my .aspx code

```
 <asp:Panel ID="DR_list" runat="server" Direction="LeftToRight" Height="227px" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" ScrollBars="Horizontal" Wrap="False">
        <asp:ListView >
        </asp:ListView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

my c # code is

```
         SqlDataReader myReader = null;
         SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select drname from --- ",
                                                  myConnection);
         myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
         while (myReader.Read())
         {
             //Response.Write(myReader["DrName"].ToString());
             int tRows;  
               int tCells;
             List<string> DrNames = new List<string>();

             for (tCells = 0; tCells < 4; tCells++)
              {
                  string a = myReader["DrName"].ToString();
                  Response.Write(a);
                    DrNames.Add(a);

              }

             DR_list.Controls.Add(DrNames);

         }
     }
```

please help me .. thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any _exception_ or..?

Comment: Your title suggests the solution. Use a `Panel` and add `ListBoxes`, but where is the code? Don't use `Response.Write`.

Comment: no but nothing comes up

Comment: You will have to be abit more specific. I assume this doesn't compile (a `List<>` is not a Control), always post full error messages.

Comment: As Tim pointed out already, it doesn't look like you are adding anything to the Panel.  That is where you need to add the controls.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add runat="server" to your panel, in order to add this data, but add data to end of your loop structure

Comment: Dr_list is my panel name . it does not have a datasource property

Comment: <asp:Panel ID="DR_list" runat="server" Direction="LeftToRight" Height="227px" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" ScrollBars="Horizontal" Wrap="False">
         
        </asp:Panel>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this as people suggesting?

```
         SqlDataReader myReader = null;
         SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select drname from --- ",
                                                  myConnection);
         myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
         while (myReader.Read())
         {
             //Response.Write(myReader["DrName"].ToString());
             int tRows;  
               int tCells;
             List<string> DrNames = new List<string>();

             for (tCells = 0; tCells < 4; tCells++)
              {
                  string a = myReader["DrName"].ToString();
                  Response.Write(a);
                    DrNames.Add(a);
              }
             //adding list box to the panel
             yourPanel.Controls.Add(new ListBox(){/*set id to the list here*/});

             DR_list.Controls.Add(DrNames);

         }
     }
```

Comment: I AM totally nave . no expert . THe list on adding to the panel gives me a compile time error . @ Dilshod does the list code come in the {}

Comment: Could you provide the error you got or the exact code you are trying?